# Website saves separate sessions for "www.domain.com" and "domain.com"

Tags: sessions

- I open a browser, type "www(dot)mydomain(dot)com"
- I login as an admin
- I open a new tab, type "mydomain(dot)com". I'm logged out, and i can login as a different user..

It's weird. I can't find anything helpful on google (or i don't know the right search keywords). Does anyone here have any idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For usability (this problem) and SEO reasons you should redirect all visitors to a single version of the site. Look in the .htaccess file and you should see instructions on how to do a 301 redirect to send people to either the www or the non-www version of the site.

If you really really do want to make the site work on both versions, open your settings.php and find the line for $cookie_domain. Set it to be the "example.com" version and it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I went to edit settings.php and saw $base_url commented out. I tried to uncomment it and tested, and it seemed to solve my problem

Comment: @Bibokid IF greggles has provide a 'correct' answer, remember to click the check on the anser to give credit.

Comment: If you can access the site with www or without the www (without the url in address bar being re-written) , you have only fixed part of your problem. Although the site works you should still consider setting it up so all url's are served via the www.hostname.com schema. This is a very important point for search engines: no duplicate pages.  In most sites I setup, the non www address space is used for CDN purposes.

Comment: thanks guys. i am working on it. Greggles have already pointed it out but thanks to stefgosselin for giving another heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my .htaccess solution for www Resolve to Apache.

Make sure to place the .htaccess file you build in the root directory of your web site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here are the three lines of code to use if you want to drop the www.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Bibokid, Great try choosing the best answer if it works.

Comment: This is only one possible way to solve it in Drupal and has the effect of redirecting all traffic to one version of the site. That *may* be desirable, but knowing all solutions is useful if this is not a desirable effect.